Problem with tailwind styling in blade component
I am trying to create a radio button where the background color changes depending on the option you select. But anytime I click on the first option the second option retains the background color. But the functionality of both options works perfectly well
This is the code block for the blade component
@props(['label', 'name'])

@php
$options = [
'Employer' => 'employer',
'Applicant' => 'applicant',
];
@endphp

<div class="flex border-2 border-teal-500 rounded-lg">
    @foreach ($options as $optionLabel => $optionValue)
    <input wire:model.live="{{ $name }}" type="radio" name="{{ $name }}" id="{{ $optionValue }}"
        value="{{ $optionValue }}" class="hidden peer">
    <label for="{{ $optionValue }}"
        class="flex-1 py-2 px-4 font-semibold cursor-pointer focus:outline-none peer-checked:bg-teal-500 peer-checked:text-white bg-white text-teal-500 transition-colors duration-200 {{ $loop->first ? 'border-r border-teal-500 rounded-l-md' : '' }} {{ $loop->last ? 'rounded-r-md' : '' }}">
        {{ $optionLabel }}
    </label>
    @endforeach
</div>


You mean the background color only added to the class of the element and not changing ?

No.I have 2 options on the radio button (Employer and Applicant). So anytime I check a particular option, it is supposed to have the background color. But here is the case the applicant option always has the background color even if it is not checked. So if I check the Employer option, both of them get the same background color.

Solved it. Thank you
